# XLConnect: It seems downloading the JAR dependencies may have failed

Tags: r, xlconnect

I have used XLConnect and XLConnectJar successfully for at least 5 years.

Have just updated R to Ver 4.0.4 and XLConnect to 1.0.2 and get the following message when attaching:

```
XLConnect: It seems downloading the JAR dependencies may have failed. If you 
would like to use a different maven repository, please set the environment 
variable XLCONNECT_JAVA_REPO_URL to a valid URL, e.g. 
Sys.setenv(XLCONNECT_JAVA_REPO_URL='https://jcenter.bintray.com'), and reinstall 
the package.
```

After following the suggested solution and re-installing I still get the message.

The package seems to work corrcetly.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and do you have a solution.

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. If you have a github account, perhaps you can submit a new [issue](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues) on the github repo?